# Loop through array and execute statement inside XTempate

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a custom component, with such a store:

```
"store":{
    "fields":["name"],
    "data":[{
        "id":"1","name":"John","checked":"truec","tools":["user","doc"]
     },{
        "id":"2","name":"Jack","checked":"false","tools":["user"]
     }]
}
```

And I have a template, which I use inside my custom `Ext.ux.CheckList`. It works good, except one tiny thing - I do not know how to loop through `tools` array. This is what I have now:

```
'<tpl for="tools">',
 // if (curValue == "user") '<div>Value 1</div>'
 // else if (curValue == "doc") '<div>Value 2</div>'           
'</tpl>'
```

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069000/extjs-xtemplate-two-same-level-array-loop) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692370/extjs-how-to-pass-component-config-options-to-xtemplates) examples, but they do not solve my problem. 
As you can see, I want to use `tools` values inside the loop:

```
if (curValue == "user") '<div>Value 1</div>'
else if (curValue == "doc") '<div>Value 2</div>'
```

But I do not know how to achieve this.

Comment: The runner variable of a XTemplate `tpl for` loop is called xindex, so you can try something like `{[console.log(values.tools[xindex])]}` and see whether it gives you what you need.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it in a minute!

Comment: `values` variable helped me to solve this problem. I did not know that it stores current array value, when you are looping (in my case - "user" and "doc" values). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Obviously, I didn't know either ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value at the current index when iterating through a flat array can be accessed with "{.}" in markup and the "values" property in conditionals.

[Sencha Fiddle: An Example of Iterating Through a Flat Array](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1uef)

```
var template = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<p>{name}</p>',
        '<tpl for="tags">',
            '<tpl if="values === \'user\'">',
                '<p>{.}</p>',
            '<tpl elseif="values === \'doc\'">',
                '<pre>{.}</pre>',
            '</tpl>',
        '</tpl>',
        '<br>',
    '</tpl>'
);
```

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?320083
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.XTemplate.html